# Is it possible to detect email clients using a server?

Tags: email, server, newsletter, device-detection

I am designing an html email newsletter. As you may know, this is a headache. We're currently going round and round with a few different email-client specific quirks like a game of whack-a-mole. You get something working in one client and it breaks another.

I know that on desktop browsers, is it possible – tho not advisable, particularly scalable, nor completely reliable – to do device detection server-side. What I am wondering is, is there any way to do server-side email client detection for html email newsletters?